# VS Code Stacking all parent folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I scroll in the exploring in VS Code. It is stacking all the folders instead of showing the files.

IT IS **NOT** COMPACT FOLDERS

Here's what's doing. All the parent folders are getting nested at the top of the explorer

[image: wrong]

I want it to be like this and show all the possible folders and files

[image: right]

VERSION

```
Version: 1.86.1 (user setup)
Commit: 31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
Date: 2024-02-07T09:08:20.941Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26495564
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```